# ¿Cómo guardar minimo entero de un "precio" en pascal?

Tags: condiciones, pascal

Tengo que guardar un "código" del "precio" mas barato en un programa de pascal, la cosa es que el profesor sabía menos que yo, y no lo probó el programa que hice, solo lo leyó y me dijo que estaba bien, pero lo estoy probando y me lee cualquier cosa, bueno, acá dejo todo el programa de pascal (lenguaje mas bugueado que este imposible.)

```
program eje9;

procedure codigoprecio(var codigo, precio:real;var tipo:String);
{var masbarato,preciobarato,codigobarato:real;}
begin
    Write('codigo,precio y tipo : ');Readln(codigo);
    ReadLn(precio);
    {
        preciobarato:=precio;
        codigobarato:=codigo;
        if precio<=preciobarato then 
        begin
            masbarato:=codigobarato;
        end;
    }
    Read(tipo);
    //WriteLn('mas barato:',masbarato);
    //WriteLn(codigo,' ',precio,' ',tipo);
end;
type cadena=String [15];
var i:Integer;
codigo,precio:real; tipo:cadena ; cantpan:Integer;
masbarato,preciobarato,codigobarato:real;
begin
    masbarato:=0;
    for i:=1 to 2 do begin
        codigoprecio(codigo,precio,tipo);
        preciobarato:=precio;
        codigobarato:=codigo;
        if precio<=preciobarato then
        begin
            preciobarato:=precio;
            codigobarato:=codigo;
        end;
    end;
    WriteLn('mas barato:' ,codigobarato);
    //WriteLn(codigo,' ',precio,' ',tipo);
    if (tipo='pantalon') then begin
        cantpan:=cantpan+1;
    end;
end.
```

Lo que me doy cuenta es que SIEMPRE entra al `if` y por eso no guarda el valor que tendría que guardar, y no se como arreglarlo, no me doy cuenta.

`Realizar un programa que lea datos de 100 productos de una tienda de ropa. Para cada producto debe leer el
precio, código y tipo (pantalón, remera, camisa, medias, campera, etc.). Informar:
- El código del producto más barato.
- El código del producto de tipo “pantalón” más caro.`

Comment: Porque decis que el lenguaje esta bugueado? pascas es un lindo lenguaje. Y a que if entra siempre? si es a este: if precio<=preciobarato then, es porque en la linea anterior hiciste preciobarato:=precio; y por lo tanto, siempre son iguales.

Comment: Me expliqué mal ahi, el programa que uso es medio basura, pero es el unico que funciona, y sobre la pregunta, como hago para arreglar eso, explicando con dibujitos el procedimiento si me di cuenta que "preciobarato" le doy el valor de "precio" y por eso siempre entra al if, pero si lo saco, nunca entra, y no es la idea.

Comment: Por lo que veo todo el programa es un gran error de logica. Esto se soluciona con muy pocas lineas. no entiendo porque tantas definiciones de variables y tantos pasajes. No entra nunca, porque al definir la variable no le diste un valor, entonces toma cualquier cosa (o el menor, no me acuerdo en pascal). Prueba a sacar la asignacion antes del if, y ponerle un valor enorme, y vas a ver como empieza a funcionar. y despide a tu profesor

Comment: Ahi parece que si, sobre las variables, es porque lo estoy haciendo un un programa, creo variables, las uso, y si veo que al final no me sirve, o no me funcionan no las uso, pero las dejo ahi, pero bueno, es por ahora, hasta que me acostumbre a usar pascal en este caso, y piense bien como hacerlo antes de escribir el codigo.
Sobre el otro punto de abajo, tienen alguna idea de como empezarlo?

Comment: igual que el de arriba, pero con un if mas que primero se fije si es pantalon, y despues haga las comprobaciones al reves para ver si es el mas caro.. En este caso, usa otras dos variables para pantalon ;)

Comment: Ahi lo hice, a mi me funciona, pero tu lo puedes probar si te lo paso?

Comment: No tengo como, pero me alegro que lo hayas arreglado. Ahora, respecto a esta pregunta, no hay mucho que podamos hacer con ella. Salvo que pongas una respuesta explicando claramente los problemas y la solución.

Answer (score 1):

***RESPUESTA (parece funcionar)***

```
program eje9;
procedure codigoprecio(var codigo, precio:real;var tipo:String);
{var
masbarato,preciobarato,codigobarato:real;}
begin

Write('codigo,precio y tipo : ');Readln(codigo);
ReadLn(precio);
{
preciobarato:=precio;
codigobarato:=codigo;
if precio<=preciobarato then begin
masbarato:=codigobarato;
end;}
Read(tipo);
//WriteLn('mas barato:',masbarato);
//WriteLn(codigo,' ',precio,' ',tipo);

end;
type
cadena=String [15];

var
i:Integer;
codigo,precio:real; tipo:cadena ; cantpan:Integer;
codigopantalon,preciobarato,preciocaro,codigobarato:real;
begin
                       preciocaro:=0;
preciobarato:=39999;
for i:=1 to 4 do begin
codigoprecio(codigo,precio,tipo);
if(tipo='pantalon')and(precio>=preciocaro) then    begin
codigopantalon:=codigo;
end;
if precio<=preciobarato then
 begin
preciobarato:=precio;
codigobarato:=codigo;
end;

end;
WriteLn('mas barato:' ,codigobarato);
//WriteLn(codigo,' ',precio,' ',tipo);
writeln('pantalon mas caro',codigopantalon);
end.
```

***Mi solución: ***
Lo que fallaba era que "preciominimo" tomaba el valor de "precio" lo que hacie que siempre entre al if, y tomaba el ultimo valor del `for` asi que como comentaron arriba, directamente a preciominimo le di un valor alto, asi entraba la primera vez, al insertar el primer "codigo y precio", y ya quedar con ese "codigo y precio", y las veces que entre al if, sea solamente porque SI se cuple la condición de ser menor el precio.